# How do I add firebase to my tvOS project?

Tags: cocoapods, firebase-analytics, tvos, tvos13

I'm trying to add firebase to my tvOS project for analytics and have followed the instructions from [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#next_steps) exactly as they have it in there but it's not working. The files Pods_BethanyChurch.framework, Pods_TopShelf.framework, FBLPromises.framework are all highlighted red in my project folder and the `import Firebase` statement that I put at the top of my AppDelegate.swift file is empty.

Does anyone have a fix for this please?

Answer (score 0):

Firebase tvOS support is community supported and the documentation is at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk#tvos-macos-watchos-and-catalyst